# How to view html files in browser window which is stored in an Amazon S3 bucket?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have an HTML file stored in an Amazon S3 bucket and also I have a presigned URL for that HTML document, Now I want to display that HTML file in my browser.
How can I display that file in the browser using angular js or node?

Comment: You can simply send the browser to that URL like any normal HTML page. Or did you have some different goal when you say "display that HTML file in my browser"?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is listed in this tutorial. If you configured you bucket as decribed in the link below, you can use this URL:

http://www.example.com

See [Configuring a static website on Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/HostingWebsiteOnS3Setup.html#step7-test-web-site)